# Why does the Glyph not working in `FontIcon`?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I've added FontAwesome 6 to my app and want to use an icon. I have the OTF file in my assets folder here:

[image: Assets/Fonts]

I want to change the default symbols (icons) for NavigationViewItems. I added the `FontIcon` however instead of the icon, I'm seeing just empty box:

[image: empty box]

The icon I'm adding is this: https://fontawesome.com/icons/tower-control?s=solid&f=classic

and my code is

```xml
<NavigationViewItem Content="Home" Tag="homePageView" x:Name="homeViewItem">
    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        <FontIcon FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/Font Awesome 6 Pro-Solid-900.otf#Font Awesome 6 Pro Solid" Glyph="&#xe2a1;" />
    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

Why is the icon not showing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Font Awesome v6 glyphs were very inconsistent, some glyphs working, some don't and some icons only working on some versions, I've decided to leave Font Awesome and switch to PNG based icons using `ImageIcon`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but, have you tried fixing the file extension (.ttf to .otf)?

```xml
<FontIcon FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/Font Awesome 6 Pro-Solid-900.otf#Font Awesome 6 Pro Solid" Glyph="&#xe2a1;" />
```

**UPDATE**

I can confirm that this works:

1. Download the [free version](https://fontawesome.com/download).
2. Create a "Fonts" folder inside the "Assets" folder.
3. Copy the "Font Awesome 6 Free-Solid-900.otf" file in the "Fonts" folder.
4. Use this code below.

```xml
<FontIcon FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/Font Awesome 6 Free-Solid-900.otf#Font Awesome 6 Free Solid" Glyph="&#xf015;" />
```

Note that I'm using `Glyph="&#xf015;"`([link](https://fontawesome.com/icons/house?s=solid&f=classic)) since I couldn't find `&#xe2a1;` in the free version.

Comment: I was trying another way of using it, I forget that I updated the code, however it doesn't work whether it's OTF or TTF. I'll edit my question now.

Comment: I just updated my answer. Can you try another icons? The "home" (&#xf015;) icon for staters.

Comment: Let me try and report back. // UPDATE: Didn't work again. I did put the exact same OTF file with same name, tried setting build property "Content", "Embedded Resource", "Resource", blank and nothing worked. Not sure what's the issue to be honest. Here's the image https://i.imgur.com/Vwgu7ja.png

Comment: UPDATE: I tried to use free version for some very basic icon, using `.ttf` file, changing property to "Resource" and calling it by its name `<FontIcon FontFamily="./Assets/Fonts/#Font Awesome 6 Pro Solid" Glyph="&#xe2a2;" />`. This did work for that one example however I don't understand why it's not working for this glyph specifically.

Comment: You mean some icons work but some don't? I guess you should get support from the maintainers then.

Comment: I let go Font Awesome as this was taking too much time. I switched to Flaticon and using png icons with `ImageIcon`. Thanks for the help Andrew!